# Get count of all types of values in a column obtained in the same SELECT SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

MySQL Version: 5.7.36

I'm attempting to minimize the amount of queries I have to execute.

Right now, I'm executing a query similar to this:

```
SELECT
    TABLE 1.column1 as "A",
    TABLE 1.column2 as "B"

FROM 
    TABLE 1
WHERE 
    CONDITION
```

I can obtain the results I need from this query, however I would also like to obtain the count of what type of values show up in the same query.

For example, if the following query retrieves this table

```
A   B
-   -
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   d
3   e
4   f
4   g
```

I would also like to, for each row, obtain the count of all rows retrieved with its column "A" that matches its value.

Would it be more efficient to execute another query to get that result or can I modify my obtaining query to get this statistic?

Desired result:

```
A   B   C
-   -   -
1   a   3   # 3 rows with "1" in Column "A"
1   b   3
1   c   3
2   d   1
3   e   1
4   f   2
4   g   2
```

UPDATE:

The closest query I could find goes like this:

```
SELECT
    TABLE 1.column1 as "A",
    COUNT(TABLE 1.column1)
FROM 
    TABLE 1
WHERE 
    TABLE 1.column1 = "foo"
GROUP BY
    TABLE 1.column1
```

Results in this:

```
A   B   C
-   -   -
1   a   3
2   d   1
3   e   1
4   f   2
```

However, it removes any other rows with the same value in column "A". Even if it has different values in column "B". I would like to have all rows present in my SQL query with its corresponding row count.

The next closest query I found goes like this:

```
SELECT
    TABLE 1.column1 as "A",
    COUNT(TABLE 1.column1)
FROM 
    TABLE 1
WHERE 
    TABLE 1.column1 = "foo"
GROUP BY
    TABLE 1.column2
```

Results in this:

```
A   B   C
-   -   -
1   a   1
1   b   1
1   c   1
2   d   1
3   e   1
4   f   1
4   g   1
```

Which also isn't achieving the desired result.

Comment: How can the values of `column1` be `1, 2, 3` if you have `WHERE column1 = 'foo'`? Shouldn't those be different columns?

Comment: @Barmar I've removed the condition, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join with the subquery that gets the counts.

```
SELECT t1.column1 AS A, t1.column2 AS B, t2.count
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT column1 AS A, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY column1
) AS t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
```

Comment: I'll try this, but I'm not sure what t2 is referring to. Is that the second column?

Comment: Sorry, t2 wsa supposed to be the subquery

Comment: I was also missing `GROUP BY` in the subquery, I fixed that. And adjusted to match the changes you've made to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  c,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c)
FROM t
ORDER BY c
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench. The OVER clause doesn't seem to be recognized by it.

Comment: @AngoMango It has nothing to do with Workbench. It just requires MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I do have that version, but the command isn't working. I have limited permissions for the user I'm executing the query on ```GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' - GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON `DB`.* TO 'user'@'%'```
, so it could be that I just don't have access to that clause.

Comment: The other solution worked, but I'll open up a separate question regarding this issue. I'll attempt this solution, too, to see if it's anymore efficient than the other answer.

Comment: Disregard, I don't have the most recent MySQL version. I have 5.7.36-google-log. I'll update the version and try again.

Comment: It looks like this could work, but the SQL server I'm currently asking does not have the updated MySQL version. It was my mistake for not pointing this out. I tested this out on another server and it worked, but it isn't the solution I can use. I'll update my question to state as such.